# jQuery Plugin ... how to add destroy method

Tags: jquery

I have created a jQuery plugin for customizing form element.... now i want to add destroy method to that and call it, but wont be able to get it done. THere is destroy method but its not work as expected and how i can call this.

The plugin Insprired by Addy Osmani Plugin structure.

```
;( function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

    var pluginName = 'yatraCustomControl',
        defaults = {
            wrapClass: 'custom-control',
            activeClass: 'ico-active',
            icoRadio: 'ico-radio',
            icoCheckbox: 'ico-checkbox'
        };

    function CustomControl( element, options ) {
        this.element = element;
        this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );

        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;

        this.init();
    }

    CustomControl.prototype.init = function(){
        this.setControl();
        this.setActive();
    };

    CustomControl.prototype.setControl = function(){
        var that = $( this.element ),
            inputType = that.attr('type'),
            cssClass;

        if( inputType === 'checkbox' ) {
            cssClass = defaults.icoCheckbox;
        } if ( inputType === 'radio' ) {
            cssClass = defaults.icoRadio;
        }   

        that.wrap('<span></span>').parent().addClass(cssClass);
    };

    CustomControl.prototype.setActive = function(){
        var that = $( this.element ),
            checkType = that.is(':checkbox');       
        checkType ? this.onCheckbox() : this.onRadio()      
    };

    CustomControl.prototype.onCheckbox = function(){
        var that = $( this.element );
        that.on('change', function() {
            if ( that.is(':checked') ) {
                that.parent().addClass( defaults.activeClass );
            } else {
                that.parent().removeClass( defaults.activeClass );
            }
        });
    };

    CustomControl.prototype.onRadio = function(){
        var that = $( this.element ),
            attrName = that.prop('name');
        that.on('change', function(){
            if ( that.is(':checked') ) {
                that.parent().addClass( defaults.activeClass );
            } else {
                that.parent().removeClass( defaults.activeClass );
            }
        });
    };

    CustomControl.destroy = function(){
        this.element.removeData();
    };

    $.fn[pluginName] = function( options ){
        return this.each( function() {
            if( !$.data( this, 'plugin_' + pluginName )) {
                $.data( this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, new CustomControl ( this, options ));
            }
        });
    }

} )( jQuery, window, document );
```

Comment: why didn't you define destroy on the prototype like everything else?

Comment: if i define as prototype how i can call on page.... even in this case i an not able to call too.

Comment: `$(theelement).data("plugin_yatraCustomControl").destroy()` the same way you would execute any of the other methods.

Comment: cool its works.... is there any way i can call without using "plugin_"

Comment: Yes, you can change how the plugin is built. simply remove plugin_ from it.